# how to remove bootstrap tags input Events from the original element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In [bootstrap-tagsinput](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) there is a functionality to bind events to the original element(input element).

ex :

```
$('input').on('beforeItemRemove', function(event) {
   // event.item: contains the item
   // event.cancel: set to true to prevent the item getting removed
});
```

But if I `destroy` the `tagsinput` and initialize it again like below,

```
$('input').tagsinput('destroy');
$('input').tagsinput();
```

`beforeItemRemove` event will fire 2 times. If I remove the `tagsinput` functionality again and initialize again. When I remove another tag `beforeItemRemove` will fire 3 times. This keeps happening when I remove and add the tagsinput functionality.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: It sounds like you're binding `beforeItemRemove` repeatedly. For ever `.on()` you should have an `.off()` (if you plan to rebind).

Answer (score 1):

try using `delegate`

```
$(document).on('beforeItemRemove', 'input', function(event) {
   // event.item: contains the item
   // event.cancel: set to true to prevent the item getting removed
});
```

though, I just went to the link you provided, attached your handler in the developer console and `destroy` / `initialzer` and it only fired once for me. Therefore it could be something else in your code which is causing you the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other comments and answers I found a way to avoid this behavior. I edited the `Destroy` function.

```
/**
 * Removes all tagsinput behaviour and unregsiter all event handlers
 */
destroy: function() {
  var self = this;

  // Unbind events
  self.$container.off('keypress', 'input');
  self.$container.off('click', '[role=remove]');

    // unbind the additional events

    self.$element.off('itemAdded');
    self.$element.off('beforeItemAdd');   
    self.$element.off('itemRemoved');     
    self.$element.off('beforeItemRemove');    

  self.$container.remove();
  self.$element.removeData('tagsinput');
  self.$element.show();
},
```